# Cannot connect to any sites via browser but I can ping them

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and is on a 1 gbps NIC.
I tried checking c:/system32/drivers/etc/hosts everything looked fine in there and I cleared all the installed browsers caches. None of them load sites they just show THIS:

[image]

Except Google Drive Which works perfectly
my DNS servers are the Google public ones (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.8.4)

[EDIT]: NSLOOKUP and ping results 
[image]

Comment: Probably not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Punctuation would go a long way to making these posts more readable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer answerable.

Answer (score 3):

From what you're describing, DNS lookups appear to be working ( because you can ping any website, apparently, and that would require a DNS lookup first ) and ICMP traffic also is getting through ( or the ping would fail ).

Therefore, it seems likely that the problem is with the HTTP traffic in particular.

- Port 80, the default HTTP port, may be firewalled, on your server or somewhere between you and the internet;
- Your server is configured to use a proxy, and the configuration is wrong or the proxy is misbehaving;
- Some network admins choose to redirect port 53 (dns) traffic to their own DNS servers and provide their own responses, which typically means they're redirecting webistes to their own webserver.

Better answers may be possible if you show output of nslookup and ping.

Comment: I own and administrate the system

Comment: Do you own and administer the network from the system through to your ISP?  If so, it's something you did.  Or, possibly, your ISP broke their internet connectivity, but that's unlikely.

Comment: Its colo'd in a datacenter in Kansas City....

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan Farrell said, it's probably a problem with HTTP traffic.  DNS appears to be working fine (I double-checked myself based on your screenshot):

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:80b::2000
      216.58.216.96
```

Because your server is located in a colo center, they might be expecting traffic on port 80 to be coming *to* rather than *from* your server.  It's possible that they're blocking traffic on that port.  You should probably double-check that they aren't blocking outgoing port 80.

I also feel that I should point out that web surfing on your server isn't best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly Enough Clicking restart then Cancel fixed evertything No idea what happened but it all works now :)

Answer (score 0):

To test that you can connect to the server on port 80 (that would eliminate a lot of possibilities in one go, including firewall, dns ...), you could do a telnet on www.google.com on port 80.

Not sure if Windows Server 2012 still has native telnet but you could try with Putty if it doesn't.